# I have used npm run build command and deployed app on heroku ,now how do I edit my local code and then push app again with the changes to heroku?

Tags: reactjs, heroku, mern, heroku-cli, npm-run

I am building a MERN App and the link for my app is https://aqueous-coast-73661.herokuapp.com/ 
The link for my github repository is https://github.com/purposeeducation/MERN_APP

Now I got two doubts :

After using the "npm run build" command is it okay that I make changes to my local code and then again use the "npm run build" command so that build will be made using all the changes being applied to my app
 *Note:I am seeing all my changes being applied when I use the "npm start" command inside my client folder.

When doubt 1 is cleared,how do I make a heroku push again , does simply using "heroku push master" the changes will be applied to my live site? If not then what is the solution?
 ***Ignore the note below if you are not cloning  my repository***

(Note

In github repository there are some minor changes in code,some issues like the bug of .map() not working at first time cause notes array is not loaded up immediately in Hooks,etc have been resolved

If you are cloning the repository a edit is there in github repository The folder MERN_APP>client>build>static/js , the path should be MERN_APP>client>build>static>js "There should be a js folder inside static folder but as I have manually uploaded each file,by mistake I uploaded the files like "2.feebdbdc.chunk.js"  directly  in static folder,even though the name appears like static/js it is actually a single folder.When you clone the repository you will get what I am saying" .)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is totally fine to push the code to heroku after locally modifying it. Heroku will rebuild the files with respect to the new changes that have been pushed. However heroku also maintains a build cache about which you can read [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#cache-behavior).

About the second point, if you have locally committed the changes then running `heroku push master` should trigger a new build.

Comment: Thanks ! But still I am a bit confused.....So you mean to say it is okay that after making changes to local code(i.e. React app) I can again use "npm run build" for React app and then push again to heroku using "heroku push master" ?  Does using "npm run build" twice won't affect my React app ?

Comment: No it won't matter. If you're manually running and "npm run build" and pushing the build files as well it doesn't matter anyway.

Comment: Thank you :) , The project was almost at end but due to the fear that using "npm run build" again will cause some error I wasn't able to push it to heroku :( But now the fear won't stop me ! Cheers to you